# Ckeditor 5: Disable upload image but keeping insert image

Tags: ckeditor

[image]

I would like to disable the functionality where the user can upload an image by picking a file from their storage system, which is imageUpload and it's triggered by clicking the left control, but keeping imageInsert which allow the user to paste a link, this is in the dropdown.

The latter depends on the former so I cannot simply disable the imageUpload plugin.
I also tried to disable or hide the upload button with css but it seems it doesn't have any specific id or class, and failed to figure how to add my own one.

Finally (this is actually the first I tried), from the API itself

> editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.get(15).isEnabled = false;

But this is ignoring the button I want to disable, this particular index disables the dropdown (insertImage) and the previous index jumps to the control at the left of the one I aim.